# Form to mail tools

Tags: php

I've just made some fixes to a web site that uses the [Form2Mail](http://scripts.ringsworld.com/form-processors/form2mail/) PHP script.  This worked on my home machine, a while back, but I have suddenly been pressured to release today, and it is already 3pm here.

I am an ASP.NET developer and know very little PHP, so if I have to improvise, writing my own version of the script is not a very feasible option.  What other options to I have that can allow me to, out of the box, cause an HTML form's submit event to result in an email being sent to a configured email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sending mails in php is very simple http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

you would just put a form that submits to something like mail.php, stick some mail code in there and you are done